# How to go backward from last page result in Azure Graph API result

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am working on getting the user from the azure active directory and showing the result in a grid with paging support.

I have referred the [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options#PagingSupport) documentation for paging.

But when I am querying the azure active directory I didn't get the `skiptoken` in last request result from graph API. Please consider below example

In my azure active directory, I am having 100 users when I am querying user 10 by 10 using filter `top=10`, I am getting the `skiptoken` up to 9th request, but for last request (10th) I am not getting any `skiptoken`, i am not able to go back to 9th page again from 10th page.

When I use the `skiptoken` obtained from 9th request with `top=10` I can go to 10th-page result but when I have useed the same `skiptoken` (since I didn't any `skiptoken` in the last request) with `previous-page=true`, I am getting 8th-page result.

How can I get the 9th-page result from 10th-page(last page)?

Comment: I've encountered the same error with not getting a skiptoken with the last page of results. You're not hallucinating! They may have fixed it with MS Graph?

Comment: Just confirmed it also happens with MS Graph. Copy this into [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer): https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=10&$skiptoken=X%2744537074020000213A6469616E6570404349453439333734322E6F6E6D6963726F736F66742E636F6D29557365725F62336332346665362D356631342D343734622D626362662D64346330396435383664633000213A6D6F6C6C7963404349453439333734322E6F6E6D6963726F736F66742E636F6D29557365725F36356462613434652D336239352D343837372D383366312D393032343663616138356665B900000000000000000000%27

Comment: A skip token is returned if the number of results in the last page match the $top parameter. Navigating to that skip token returns an empty result... with no skip token!

Comment: I'm experiencing same error still in 2020. Only solution I could come up with was to store last 2 skiptoken-s and in case of last page use the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried this myself and don't seem to be able to reproduce the same issue you are experiencing.

I can only suggest at this stage you try debugging your code further to ensure that you are using the *skiptoken* parameter properly. Another suggestion at this stage would be to test your queries using the [Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net/), which I have also tried and it appears to work as expected against the demo tenant which is available.

Comment: Even on Graph explorer i can reproduce this issue.

Comment: Interesting, can you share the query you are sending please? Also confirm if this is against your tenant or the demo company?

Comment: Just use below link to test paging with 50 results on demo company it has 128 users [here](https://graph.windows.net/graphdir1.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6&$top=50). you can go to 51 to 100 and 100 to 128 but you cannot get results from 100 to 51 with `previous-page=true` fiter

Comment: Ok so I just got to the last page of the results using `skiptoken` then when on the last page I appended to the URL `&previous-page=true`. The formatted URL is pretty long but it's certainly worked for me. Here is the URL without the token: https://graph.windows.net/graphdir1.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6&%24top=50&$skiptoken=X'token'&previous-page=true

Comment: Yes, I too got the result but it is actually the result of 0 to 50 not 51  to 100, that only i mentioning here. Can you able to see `skiptoken` in the last result ?

Comment: The last result doesn't have a `skiptoken` because it's the last result set that's returned. Can you confirm you have understood how this works from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options) page? It explains how to use the `skiptoken` and `previous-page` parameters to achieve what you are after. Another example can also be found on [MSDN](http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/archive/2013/09/18/enhancing-graph-api-queries-with-additional-odata-supported-queries.aspx).

Comment: Finally, I find a way to explain you. Try like this for 128 users if get 50 as count we get 3 pages i.e. 1->2->3 now with`previous-page=true` to last page request, now you can go to the previous page and `skiptoken` obtained from this page with`previous-page=true` in URL you cannot not get any result why ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108501/discussion-between-martyn-c-and-mahendran).

Comment: Can you able to go like this 1->2->3 and 3->2->1 in the result ?

Comment: Yes, as I've said a couple of times it works perfectly for me, you must be doing something wrong. That's why I included links to a couple of good sources of documentation.